# How to speed up nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have the following Python 2.7 code:

```
listOfLists = []
for l1_index, l1 in enumerate(L1):
    list = []
    for l2 in L2:
        for l3_index,l3 in enumerate(L3):
            if (L4[l2-1] == l3):
                value = L5[l2-1] * l1[l3_index]
                list.append(value)
                break
    listOfLists.append(list)
```

with the L1,L2,L3,L4,L5 lists being:

```
L1 = [[0.60, 0.95, 0.38, 1.02, 0.29, 0.43], [0.40, 0.09, 0.87, 0.85, 0.70, 0.46], [0.67, 0.91, 0.66, 0.79, 0.86, 0.06], [0.59, 1.81, 0.05, 1.88, 0.20, 0.48], [0.64, 0.34, 0.37, 1.39, 0.56, 0.27], [0.56, 0.34, 0.68, 2.79, 0.18, 0.42], [0.42, 1.67, 0.04, 0.44, 0.25, 0.94], [0.32, 1.92, 0.95, 2.85, 0.95, 0.96], [0.50, 0.68, 0.84, 1.79, 0.35, 0.09], [0.34, 0.66, 0.85, 0.35, 0.38, 0.59], [0.50, 0.79, 0.45, 2.93, 0.50, 0.92], [0.11, 0.11, 0.93, 1.11, 0.81, 0.49]]  # a list of 12 sublists
L2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
L3 = [480, 120, 35, 0, 520, 300]
L4 = [120, 120, 120, 0, 300, 35, 35, 520, 300, 480, 120, 480, 0, 35, 0, 0, 300]
L5 = [5.4, 2.83, 1.16, 6.9, 0.76, 2.15, 5.61, 3.12, 1.57, 0.08, 5.36, 0.2, 1.2, 1.4, 2.9, 2.1, 3.5]
```

These are only examples; in reality the lists contain hundreds of thousands of numbers. The interpreter takes tens of seconds to calculate the three nested `for` loops.

Is it possible to somehow speed up this code, e.g. using `itertools` or any other module/function?

EDIT: I can not use non-standard python 2.7 modules (numpy, scipy...)

Comment: are the lists part of a larger data structure, then numpy should be able to do the job

Comment: @ChristianSauer Thank you for the reply, and I apologize for not mentioning that I can not use any python 2.7 module which requires additional installation, like numpy.

Comment: Could you provide the length of each vector? If they are at the same length you can use `zip`. You can also use list comprehension thought it will be too ugly to read.

Comment: @spacegoing, the readability is not important as long as it speeds up the code. Here are the lengths of upper lists: L1 - 12 subLists with 6 items in each, L2 - 13 items, L3 - 6 items, L4 - 17 items, L5 - 17 items. So the number of items in each L1 sublist should be equal to the number of items in the L3 list. Also the number of items in L4 and L5 are always equal.

Comment: Could you maybe write the code in C/C++ and import it into Python (https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html) ?

Comment: @Pylinux Thank you for the reply. I am not sure, I have never been coding in C/C++. Isn't there a more pythonic way of using ```itertools```, ```lambda```, ```zip```?

Comment: Since we do not know what data in your list means and what kind of operation you are trying to perform, it's hard to even conceptualize an answer. Bottom line is not _how to speed up nested loop_, is _do I even need nested loop to achieve what I want_. To rephrase - you need to find better algorithm to perform operation you want (or maybe rethink used data structure). Nested looping is always troublesome, as it effectively makes problem something like `O(n^m)` if lists are about same size `n` and there is `m` nested loops. Switching to compiled language won't change complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the information Rogalski. I do not think the meaning of the actual numbers will be of much help. They are essentially coefficients of correction, flow speeds and directions.
Why aren't the upper posted values suffice enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Rogalski is right, you definitely need to rethink the algorithm (at least try to).

But if you can't find a better algorithm, I think you could speed up a bit by some tricks while still using nested loops. Note that I will treat L* lists as some global variables, which I don't need to pass to every function. So, you need to either keep those lists visible to new functions or add them as parameters.

First of all, try to clean-up. For example, you seem to never use l1_index, so you can get rid of it. Then you can move everything that happens inside the first loop to a function. It will then look like this:

```
listOfLists = []
for l1 in L1:
    listOfLists.append(create_list(l1))

def create_list(l1):
    list = []
    for l2 in L2:
        for l3_index,l3 in enumerate(L3):
            if (L4[l2-1] == l3):
                value = L5[l2-1] * l1[l3_index]
                list.append(value)
                break
    return list
```

This is nice, but comprehensions are faster than loop with appends ([here](http://leadsift.com/loop-map-list-comprehension/) you can find a nice article on the topic). And the first loop is quite simple, so let's collapse it into `listOfLists = [create_list(l1) for l1 in L1]`. And we can perform same inner loop extraction on our create_list function

```
list_of_lists = [create_list(l) for l in L1]

def create_list(l):
    return [find_next(l, element) for element in L2]

def find_next(l, element):
    for l3_index, l3_element in enumerate(L3):
        if (L4[element - 1] == l3_element):
            return L5[element - 1] * l[l3_index]
```

now it looks more readable, and should work a bit faster. You could also try to use built-in list function for finding element in list (`l3_index = l3.index(L4[element-1])`, ), but I don't know if it will be any faster.

Note that lambdas are not faster than usual functions doing same thing in same way. But they do spoil stack-traces and thus make code harder to debug. As of itertools, you could use combinations, but then you will need to pre-generate the list_of_lists, because there is no contract on order in which combinations are given to you. And zip is just not what you need.

One of the problems with the code is that you loop through L3 in each round of the nested loop. Solution to this problem is to add some precalculations. What you need is to know for each element of L4 a corresponding index of L3. You could do it this way:

```
# this will allow you to get index by element at a constant time
# and it only takes O(N)
L3_dict = {element:index for element,index in enumerate(L3)}

list_of_lists = [create_list(l) for l in L1]

def create_list(l):
    return [find_next(l, element) for element in L2]

def find_next(l, element):
    # if you use dict, you reduce time of this method from O(N) to constant
    # as both access to dict item by key and to list item by index
    # are done in a constant time
    l3_index = L3_dict[L4[element-1]]
    return L5[element-1] * l[l3_index]
```

Comment: Spasibo Alissa!

I do use ```l1_index``` but I did not post the code which uses it. Nevertheless I can live without the ```l1_index``` variable.
Believe it or not the upper code you posted actually takes more to execute then the one in my initial reply. It's 0.5 seconds slower.

Is there some speed drawback in using list comprehensions?

Comment: that's strange, usually constructions like `[smth(i) for i in someList]` are faster than ones like `for i in someList: newList.append(smth(i))` What would happen if you replace first lines with `list_of_lists = [[find_next(l,element) for element in L2] for l in L1]`?

Comment: by the way, do you have any control on your input? If you transform some of them into dicts, you could save a huge amount of time... You said there are coefficients, those usually can be stored in a dict

Comment: Hi @Alissa. Thank you for another suggestion. Sadly ```list_of_lists = [[find_next(l,element) for element in L2] for l in L1]``` resulted in the same run time as non threaded version. I also not sure why comprehension list yield the same run time.
I do have control over inputs. Do you advise putting ```l1``` elements in a ```L1_dictionary```?

Comment: No, I meant that you could identify pairs of lists that are matched by simple rules and make them dicts. E.g. l3_index is an index of element matching certain element from L4. Can you make a dict that will have L4 elements for keys and l3 indices for value (you won't to iterate through L3 then)

Comment: So I would have to iterate through ```L3```, find which of its ```l3_element```  is equal to ```L4``` element, and then put that pair in a dictionary. Then call those pairs from the ```find_next``` function. Right? How does this decrease the run time if the iteration through ```L3``` is not avoided?

Comment: First of all, you won't need to iterate over L3 again and again in each loop if you do it beforehand. Currently you have 3 nested loops, but if you add this pre-looping you would have one loop that is not nested and 2 nested loops. But if you have control over input (or over the code it comes from), you might be able to form dictionary without all this looping

Comment: Thank you Alissa. But in order to create that dictionary, I need to do a looping of ```L3``` list?

Comment: I added explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Alissa.
Shouldn't the ```L3_dict = {element:index for element,index in enumerate(L3)}``` be ```L3_dict = {element:index for index,element in enumerate(L3)}```? Is this the only change?

Comment: Oh, it sure should, I'm sorry. And note that `find_next()` method is also changed

Comment: I have just checked your new edited code. It's faster than spacegoing's. However, I 

tried combining it with spacegoing's by introducing your dictionary approach. This third solution 

yielded the fastest times! I post it below. I marked your answer as the right one. I would like to 

thank you for the time, knowledge and patience that you shared. Spasibo!!

Answer (score 8):

Since you said `the readability is not important as long as it speeds up the code`, this is how you do the trick:

```
[[L5[l2 - 1] * sl1 for sl1, l3 in zip(l1, L3)
     for l2 in L2 if L4[l2 - 1] == l3]
 for l1 in L1]
```

This code is 25% faster than for loop. But trust me I will shoot him whoever wrote this in my code.

Comment: Thank you @spacegoing! Indeed the code is quicker now!
Does it actually need to be put in three lines like you did it?
And will it be even more quicker if it's only one line?

Comment: @marco You are welcome. That format style is only for your readability. The speed are all the same no matter how you format them.

Comment: Understood. Thank you once again.
Is it possible to post your name, so that I can credit you in the source code?

Comment: @marco Thank you very much for your kindness. I'd rather you don't mention me in your code so people can't hate me back lol.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a combination of both @spacegoing and @Alissa, and yields the fastest results:

```
L3_dict = {l3:l3_index for l3_index,l3 in enumerate(L3)}

list_of_lists = [[L5[l2 - 1] * l1[L3_dict[L4[l2-1]]]
     for l2 in L2]
 for l1 in L1]
```

Thank you both @spacegoing and @Alissa for your patience and time.